# on submit html form with enctype multipart a compile warning generate

Tags: forms, image, codeigniter, warnings, enctype

In codeigniter when i submit a html form with image upload it give me an compile warning it run on local ok but on cpanel it give this error

```
A PHP Error was encountered
```

Severity: Compile Warning

Message: Unexpected character in input: '' (ASCII=14) state=0

Filename: lib/rules.php

Line Number: 889

Backtrace:

this is my form

```
<form action="<?= base_url();?>admin/test" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="staff_images">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

and this is my method

```
public function test(){
    $this->load->view('test');
}
```

Comment: does this happen with all images, or just one specific?

Comment: only less size images properly uploads like less than 20kb this size also not fix but on local all size images upload

Comment: see: [Change the maximum upload file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/change-the-maximum-upload-file-size) and https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/360050872453-How-to-increase-the-maximum-file-upload-size-limit-in-PHP